# Package with JSON.NET is very large

Tags: android, linker, xamarin.android, json.net

I am using JSON.NET for parsing JSON in my Mono for Android application. But when I make a package, the resulting file is 17 MB with Linking: None.
With Linking turned on, the package size is reduced to 4 MB, but I get an error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.
```

I suspect, that the linking went wrong, but I don't know why. I would like to reduce the size of my package, though. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you including Json.Net?  If you download the source you can compile a DLL for your targeted project.  In my case, the .dll is only ~300kb.

Comment: @ColoradoMatt yes, the dll is ~300 kB, but the problem is, that I have to turn off Linking in order for JSON.NET to work and then all the other assemblies bloat the package

Answer (score 2):

Linking turned on will throw away any methods, attributes, properties... that are not used at the time of compilation. This is problem for example with reflection approach.

Your problem - very large package can be solved by:

1. reducing library code - removing unused code manually and linking off - probably don't want to do that
2. using DataContractJsonSerializer - application using this class is significantly smaller
3. live with 17 MB app, after all it still bearable :) And linking "Sdk assemblies only" could help also a little bit

Comment: 1. this would require editing .NET libraries
2. I doubt using DataContractJsonSerializer, because the size doesn't come from JSON.net but from the other assemblies
3. I can live with the size, but it can look suspicious to potential users

Answer (score 0):

Use the Json.Net provided by the [Xamarin Component Store](http://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net/). I have used this component for multiple projects and my Release builds with linking enabled come in between 4-8 MB.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by adding the System assembly to the "Skip linking assemblies" list under Mono Android Options for the project. This added < 1 Mb to the size of the APK for me.